# Proof verification: Find all intermediate fields of degree 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f = X^3 - 3X^2 + 3X - 6 \in \mathbb Q[X]$ and let $\zeta$ be a third root of unity. Let $L$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$. The goal is to find all intermediate fields $\mathbb Q \subseteq E \subseteq L$ with $[L : E] = 3$.

**What the other part already showed:** $f$ is irreducible, $\alpha_i = 1 + \zeta^i \sqrt[3]{5}, i = 0,1,2$ are the roots of $f$, $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5}, \zeta)$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \cong S_3$.

**What I want to do:** Find all intermediate fields $\mathbb Q \subseteq E \subseteq L$ with $[L : E] = 3$.

### My proof

Since $\operatorname{Gal}(f) \cong S_3$, the galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ contains $|S_3| = 6$ automorphisms. Since $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5}, \zeta)$, these are determined by their actions on $\sqrt[3]{5}$ and $\zeta$ such that
$$ \sigma_{k,l}: \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta^k \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \mapsto \zeta^l\end{cases}, \quad k=0,1,2, \,\, l = 1,2 $$
are six and hence all elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$.

Since $\{1, \sqrt[3]{5}, (\sqrt[3]{5})^2\}$ is a $\mathbb Q$-base of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5})$ and $\{1, \zeta\}$ is a $\mathbb Q$-base of $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$, a $\mathbb Q$-base of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5}, \zeta)$ is given by
$$ \{ 1, \sqrt[3]{5}, (\sqrt[3]{5})^2, \zeta, \zeta \sqrt[3]{5}, \zeta (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 \}. $$
Since $L/\mathbb Q$ is finite, galois correspondence holds, that is, an intermediate field $\mathbb Q \subseteq E \subseteq L$ with $[L: E] = 3$ corresponds with a subgroup $U \leq S_3$ with $|G: U| = 3$, hence $|U| = 2$. The subgroups of order $2$ are exactly the cyclic subgroups generated by the transpositions
$$ \langle (12) \rangle \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \end{cases} \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \mapsto \zeta^2 \end{cases} = \sigma_{1,2} =: \sigma$$
$$\langle (13) \rangle \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{5} \end{cases} \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \mapsto \zeta^2 \end{cases} = \sigma_{2,2} =: \tau$$
$$\langle (23) \rangle \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} \end{cases} \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{5} \\ \zeta \mapsto \zeta^2 \end{cases} = \sigma_{0,2} =: \mu$$

That is, there are exactly the three intermediate fields $L^{\langle \sigma \rangle}$, $L^{\langle \tau \rangle}$ and $L^{\langle \mu \rangle}$. Precisely: Every $x \in L$ can be written as
$$ x = \alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{5} + \gamma (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 + \delta \zeta + \epsilon \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} + \phi \zeta (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 $$
with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \phi \in \mathbb Q$. Then we have
$$ 
\sigma(x) = \alpha + \beta \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} + \gamma \zeta^2 (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 + \delta \zeta^2 + \epsilon \sqrt[3]{5} + \phi \zeta (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 \implies L^{\langle \sigma \rangle} = \mathbb Q(\zeta (\sqrt[3]{5})^2), \\
\tau(x) = \alpha + \beta \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} + \gamma \zeta (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 + \delta \zeta^2 + \epsilon \zeta \sqrt[3]{5} + \phi (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 \implies L^{\langle \tau \rangle} = \mathbb Q(\zeta \sqrt[3]{5}), \\
\mu(x) = \alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{5} + \gamma (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 + \delta \zeta^2 + \epsilon \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} + \phi \zeta^2 (\sqrt[3]{5})^2 \implies L^{\langle \mu \rangle} = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5}, (\sqrt[3]{5})^2).
$$
So all intermediate fields $\mathbb Q \subseteq E \subseteq L$ with $[L: E] = 3$ are $\mathbb Q(\zeta (\sqrt[3]{5})^2)$, $\mathbb Q(\zeta \sqrt[3]{5})$ and $Q(\sqrt[3]{5}, (\sqrt[3]{5})^2)$. $\blacksquare$

---

### My questions

1. Is this the right way to do it? The cleanest way? The smartest way?
2. Is there any easier way to do it? For me, my proof seems a bit complicated. Can it be shortened?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.  The site is not a proof-checking machine.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited the question. The question is actually not to get verified each little step but to get verified the general way of doing it in this case. Thanks for the hint, i clarified it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intermediate fields with $ [L:E]=3 $ are the fixed fields of subgroups with $|U|=3$ not with $[G:U]=2$.
That is only $A_3$ and the fixed field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ (which is much easier to check).

The rest seems to be correct; you found all intermediate fields with
$[L:E] = 2$.

I don't think this can be shortened in any easy way. You could try to find enough intermediate fields of the right degree instead of explicitly looking at the automorphisms. But then you would need to prove that these are indeed different which can be difficult (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta (\sqrt[3]{2})^2)$ are the same field)